# Gooseberry banner

Tags: discussion

Could we not have a banner (on the right side) which promote the support for Gooseberry project, as there are 4000 visitors/day here on Blender.SE? It could be a good lever for the project, or at least a nice visibility. No?

http://gooseberry.blender.org/press-banners-promotion/

Comment: Good idea. I would like to see this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately not, beta sites don't get community ads.

Comment: It would be great!! But who can do it? How to do it?

Comment: @Polosson I believe the SE employees have to set it up (I don't remember all of the details off hand; been a while).

Comment: Owkay, so... How to contact them? We should hurry...

Comment: I will contact them either tonight or tomorrow. If I don't reply by tomorrow night ping me (by commenting) to remind me.

Comment: These community-chosen ads only appear when a site graduates from beta. @Polosson

Comment: My understanding is that beta sites don't have Community Ads. That is a graduated site only thing. Dunno what would happen if you brought that up with SE.

Comment: @RolandiXor Ping, hurry up the campaign will be over soon ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have bad news :(

Beta sites don't get community ads :(

Comment: That's unfortunate. Any other way we could try to advertize it on here?

Comment: @Keavon The chat rooms.